# Unhandled GraphQL Subscription error

Tags: graphql, subscriptions, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I am using apollo client with the additional module `subscriptions-transport-ws` and graphql on the server.

When a graphql error happens on the server, kind of `cannot return null for non-nullable...` the Browser tells me that there is a apollo has a "Unhandled GraphQL subscription errror".

How does the error handling for subscriptions on the client side work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to get the error to report then just add `,onError: err => console.error(err)` below the `updateQuery` in your subscription and it reports errors. If you are asking how it all works then that's beyond me, sorry.